# Passing field metadata as keyword arguments is deprecated

Tags: python, marshmallow

During pytest test execution I noticed a warning indicating the following:

```
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow/fields.py:222: RemovedInMarshmallow4Warning: Passing field metadata as keyword arguments is deprecated. Use the explicit `metadata=...` argument instead. Additional metadata: {'places': 0}
    RemovedInMarshmallow4Warning,

module test_get_record_not_found
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py:211: DeprecationWarning: Importing 'itsdangerous.json' is deprecated and will be removed in ItsDangerous 2.1. Use Python's 'json' module instead.
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
```

The test is a simple get contact not found:

```
def test_get_record_not_found(test_client,db_session):
    get_resp = test_client.get(
        f'/record/0')
    get_data = json.loads(get_resp.data.decode())

    assert get_resp.status_code == 404
    assert 'not found' in get_data['message']
```

Do you know how could I get rid of the above warning?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell from the OP, you need to show more code.

From the error message, there must be some place in your code where you define a schema like this:

```py
class MySchema(ma.Schema):
    fields = ma.fields.Field(places=0)
```

You should change this into:

```py
class MySchema(ma.Schema):
    fields = ma.fields.Field(metadata={"places":0})
```

Assuming this is really what you want to do. It may be a mistake in the first place when building the schema. If the schema is built dynamically, we need to know how.